# How to call 32bit unmanaged DLL from "Any CPU/64bit" build project?

Tags: c#, dll, 32bit-64bit, unmanaged

I must call a 32bit unmanaged DLL from an external provider from my C# WinForms project.

However I must build my C# project as "Any CPU" to take advantage of the greater memory on 64bit computers.

Therefore, when I try to call the 32bit DLL from a machine running 64bit, I get this error:

```
BadImageFormatException : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format
```

Changing the build to target x86 is not an option for us.

We do not have any ability to modify the external DLL itself.

How can I get around this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't change your project to x86 only then you cannot call the 32bit DLL directly.  You'll have to create a 32 bit process that calls the DLL then use some inter-process communication to talk between your 64 bit process and the 32 bit hosting processing.

Comment: Thanks. We've gone with this and implemented a named pipes solution in a seperate EXE.